# how to know when and where a textfield is focused in an android webview?

Tags: android, android-layout

Normally when a native textfield in an android view is focused, the view scrolls automatically to keep the field visible when the virtual keyboard appears. And it's normally the same behaviour when I select a textfield in a webview (so I mean a html text input in the page that loaded in the webview). 
But for some reason, it doesn't work in my case. I have a webview that displays a form and when a select a textfield, the view scrolls down to the bottom of the page and the field I selected is no longer visible. What should I check in my app to prevent this to happen? If you need more details, just ask. In this way I can show you directly what you need.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: on android 4, this is not happening. I encountered the problem on android 2.2 and 2.3.

Comment: in my own experience the WebView is a bit buggy if it comes to Forms inside. Only the WebView is beeing focused, not any other HTML that may be inside

Answer (score 0):

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Add above tag in your manifest file's activity tag. The activity will be the one which displays webview

Comment: I have a TabActivity that includes the one containing the webview. Which softinputmode should I put on it?

Comment: with adjustPan|adjustResize it doesn't change anything

Comment: I have the same case. What I have is one header , Tabs in footer and middle content is webview. Webview is form kind of thing and below code works jst fine with me <activity
            android:name=".BookEventActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/NoBackgroundTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>